# Find corresponding array in a cell

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a cell of arrays of the same size, for example

```
arr = {[1   NaN 2  ], ...
       [NaN 4   7  ], ...
       [3   4   NaN]  };
```

and I also have a vector, for example

```
vec = [1 2 2];
```

How do I find the corresponding cell entry that matches the vector `vec`. Matching means the entries in the same location are the same, except for `NaN`s?

For this particular vector `vec` I would like to have `1` returned, since it matches the first row.

Another vector `[5 4 7]` would return `2`.

Vectors that don't match like `[7 7 7]` and vectors that match more than one entry like `[3 4 7]` should throw an error.

Note that the vector `[3 7 4]` does not match the second entry, because the order is important.

Comment: So, `NaN` for you means "Whatever" rigth?

Comment: Yes. `NaN` is arbitrarily chose. I could have chosen `42` for this as well, but this seemed unintuitive.

Comment: Are all cells always row vectors of the same length?

Comment: Why are you using a cell array instead of a normal matrix?

Comment: remember `NaN == NaN` is `false` ;)

Comment: All vectors have the same length. I use a cell array because the vectors in the cell are actually matrices in my real application, where I want to match the first rows. I know I need to use `isnan` for comparing `NaN`s.

Comment: try this `cellfun(@(x) (isnan(x(1))||x(1)==1)&&(isnan(x(2))||x(2)==2)&&(isnan(x(3))||x(3)==2),arr,'UniformOutput', false)`

Comment: See my own answer below, I did use `cellfun` as well.

Comment: So, does `[3 7 4]` match the third entry?

Comment: It does not. A vector `a` (containing `NaN`s) matches a vector `b`, iff by replacing all `NaN`s by certain numbers, one can achive `all(a_replaced == b) == true`.

Comment: @Wauzl and before me! :D +1

Answer (score 1):

For each cell element, just check if

```
all(isnan(cellElement) | cellElement == vec)
```

is true, which means, you found a match. If you convert your cell to a matrix `checkMatrix` with multiple rows and each row corresponding to one `cellElement`, you can even do it without implementing a loop by repeating vec vertically and comparing the whole matrix in a single step. You will have to tell all() to check along dimension 2 rather than dimension 1 and have find() detect all the matches, like so:

```
find( all( ...
    isnan(checkMatrix) | checkMatrix == repmat(vec,size(checkMatrix, 1),1) ...
    , 2)); % all() along dimension 2
```

Comment: This does not throw an error for no or multiple matches, but this can be checked easily after `find`.

Answer (score 1):

See if this [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based approach works for you -

```
A = vertcat(arr{:});
matching_ind = find(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,vec(:).') | isnan(A),2)) %//'
if numel(matching_ind)~=1
    error('Error ID : 42.')
else
    out = matching_ind(1);
end
```

Comment: This does not work. For example `vec= [3 7 4]` "matches" the second and third cell entry, where it should not.

Comment: I like the use of `bsxfun(@eq,...)`.

Answer (score 1):

So I thought about it and came up with this:

```
matching_ind = @(x, arr) find(...
   cellfun(@(y) max(abs(not(x-y==0).*not(isnan(x-y)))),...
           arr)                   == 0);

inds = matching_ind(vec, arr);

if length(inds) ~= 1
   error('42');
end
```